# Is there a script that would allow me to edit multiple files as if they are one file in VIM?

Tags: vim, vi

I prefer to edit in one large file rather than many independent files, but due to limitations in languages, source control, and the preference of team mates I need to output to many files.

What I'm looking for would recurse through all the files in a source directory and generate a single file to edit in VIM, with special file seperator markers. On save it would save the the changes to the correct file(s) ideally in a smart manner, based only on changes made.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: Do you use `C-W` to split up the screen at all? I usually split the screen into however many files I need to edit at one time.

Comment: Although I agree with you that editing that way is much faster for a single person. With more than 1 person it's bound to give problems and hard to resolve conflicts eventually ;) So I can't blame your teammates for wanting to restrict that a little (having that said, I prefer fewer files aswell). Either way... I don't know a Vim script that does this but I creating something like this (atleast externally) should be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

#### shar

Well, you could use `shar(1)`, but it puts an `X` in front of each line that you will probably find annoying. (Shar came with my Mac but on my Linux systems you need to add a package.)

Shar is just, itself, a short shell script, so you could modify it easily enough to work without the X.

You might try copying /usr/bin/shar to /tmp and applying this diff with `patch(1)`.

```
--- /usr/bin/shar   2009-07-13 22:26:18.000000000 -0700
+++ /tmp/shar2  2010-12-24 19:05:34.000000000 -0800
@@ -65,8 +65,8 @@
        echo "mkdir -p $i > /dev/null 2>&1"
    else
        echo "echo x - $i"
-       echo "sed 's/^X//' >$i << 'END-of-$i'"
-       sed 's/^/X/' $i
+       echo "cat >$i << 'END-of-$i'"
+       cat $i
        echo "END-of-$i"
    fi
 done
```

Comment: can you link to some tutorials of `shar`? It looks like a neat command and I havent come across it till now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It reminds me of vimballs format. However, it's meant to expand files into the user runtimepath directory.

In other words, you can list all the files you want join and apply `:MkVimBall` (here is [an example](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/vim-lib/trunk/mkVba/mk-lh-vim-lib.vim?r=320)).
Then, for the extraction, you will have to momentarily (i.e. save and restore its value after the extraction) set `&runtimepath` to the root directory of your project before extracting with `:so %`.

You'll also have to play with various options like the `&filetype`, etc.

It's a dirty hack, but well ... it shall do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dumping several files into one, processing this one and then separating stuff apart again, you could use `bufdo` or `windo` to repeat a command on all opened buffers: open the buffers to be processed, then cast the `bufdo` command and it will work on every opened file: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#list-repeat